# Terminal window appears along with pygame window upon launch of the exe

Tags: python, pygame, cx-freeze

I made a game using pygame and built it using cx_Freeze, now when I run the executable it launches a console window along with the pygame window, is there any way to remove/disable this window

Comment: Is this the window that pops up saying ‘welcome to pygame...’?

Comment: Yes, it says something along the lines of welcome to pygame with a link to a webpage

Comment: In your site packages find the pygame folder. Within the folder the init file has the offending language. You can edit it out. Just note that if you update the package you’ll probably have to edit the new package.

Comment: I deleted the line... it does not print the version and welcome message but still opens the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it

In the cx_Freeze setup file you need to add the line

```
base = “WIN32GUI”
```

When declaring your exeacutable